# Web service to connecting with an OTP (One Time Password)

Tags: java, web-services, sms, one-time-password

As stated in the title of the post I have a project which consists of designing a web service that will allow users to connect with an OTP. I really searched the internet and I found that there is a Java API for sending SMS (SMSLib) but regarding the generation of the OTP on the server side and sending it which is done through the web service I have to do, I did not find anything.
Can you please help me by showing me some tutorials talking about this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Can you please provide some specifics, such as, target programming language? How do you want the OTP delivered(via SMS?).

You may be able to use the Amazon Simple Notification service for the SMS : http://aws.amazon.com/sns/

Generally, you are better off letting the user pick their password from the start if possible.

**EDIT:**

As for generating the OTP, you are probably best off using something randomly generated as opposed to hashing something.  You could try a UUID version 4.  Details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29

PHP has a method uniqid() which gives you a guaranteed unique string, similar to this: 4b3403665fea6

One more thing I thought of on the SMS, the company http://cdyne.com has a web service you can connect to send SMS.  They have a text to speech service for actually placing calls too.

I still don't understand where OTP fits into your authentication model, so, for me to be of much more help there, you will need to give me some more specifics.

Comment: in fact the page will contain two fields one for the login and the other for the password . Then when the authentification is done the OTP will be generated on the server side and sent via SMS

Comment: So, the user will enter a username and password, then they will receive an SMS with the OTP?

Comment: Updated my answer with some more details.

Comment: yes and this OTP will finish the second step for the authentification

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following resources which describe in detail how to code a one time password service using either a counter or time based algorithm.

Both examples show a reference implementation, also showing the protection against hacking attempts that need to be implemented (such as throttling)

[One Time Password](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226)
[Time Based One Time Password](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238)